# Proof of factorization at late times for chaotic systems

Tags: quantum-field-theory, density-operator, many-body, chaos-theory, thermal-field-theory

While reading the paper "A bound on Chaos - Maldacena et. al", https://arxiv.org/abs/1503.01409 in equation (23) of the paper they factorize a correlator of the form, 
$$ Tr [\rho^{1/2} W(t) V \rho^{1/2} V W(t)] \leq Tr [\rho^{1/2} W(t) \rho^{1/2} W(t)] Tr [\rho^{1/2} V \rho^{1/2} V] + \epsilon , $$ where $V$ is time zero, $\epsilon$ is a small error.

This step is not entirely clear to me, is there a way to derive this?